# Comparação de dados Entity Framework asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Eu preciso receber o valor e a quantidade em estoque de um determinado produto de acordo com seu Id.Pelo debug o id do produto está chegando corretamente, mas quando vou atribuir o valores aos campos da tabela estou com erro na conversão.

```
        // POST: Pedidos/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Pedido model)
    {
         //pego a quantidade do produto de acordo com id
        var qtdEstoque = db.Estoque.Where(p => p.ProdutoId == model.ProdutoId).Select(p => p.Quantidade);
        //pego preço de acordo com id
        var precoUnitario = db.Produto.Where(p => p.Id == model.ProdutoId).Select(p => p.Preco);

        model.PrecoUnidade = Convert.ToDecimal( precoUnitario);
        model.Quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(qtdEstoque);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pedido.Add(model);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Cliente.ToList(), "Id", "Nome");
        ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(db.Produto.ToList(), "Id", "Nome");

        return View(model);

    }

    [Table("Pedido")]
public class Pedido
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public decimal PrecoUnidade { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProdutoId")]
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Decimal]' no tipo 'System.IConvertible'.'

Comment: Tentou usar Double?

Comment: Ele nem deixa porque campo na tabela está como decimal, se eu digitar na mão funciona, mas se eu tentar já pegar o valor do produto no banco não vai =/

Answer (score 0):

Ficou assim:

```
            Estoque estoque = db.Estoque.Where(x => x.ProdutoId == model.ProdutoId).FirstOrDefault();
        int qtdEstoque = estoque.Quantidade;

        Produto produto = db.Produto.Where(x => x.Id == model.ProdutoId).FirstOrDefault();
        decimal precoUnitario = produto.Preco;

        model.Quantidade = qtdEstoque;
        model.PrecoUnidade = precoUnitario;
```